# Cantor Set Recursion Issue (Homework)

Tags: function, graphics, recursion

I'm working on a homework to create a program that takes one argument "n" and creates a cantor line of that depth, but it does not seem to be working. I think there's a problem with variable scope and functions. This is the first time I work with functions and recursion, so I'm a little confused still. I have three functions, one to draw the relative left line, the relative right line, and the cantor function which calls itself twice and calls both draw functions.

```
public class Art
{
public static void drawLeftLine(double x0, double y0, double x1, double y1)
{
    double x2 = (1/3.0)*(x1 - x0);
    double x3 = x0;
    double y2 = y0 - 0.1;
    double y3 = y1 - 0.1;

    StdDraw.line(x2, y2, x3, y3);

}

public static void drawRightLine(double x0, double y0, double x1, double y1)
{

    double x2 = (2/3.0)*(x1 - x0);
    double x3 = x1;
    double y2 = y0 - 0.1;
    double y3 = y1 - 0.1;

    StdDraw.line(x2, y2, x3, y3);

}

public static void cantor(int n, double x0, double y0, double x1, double y1)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return;

    drawLeftLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
    drawRightLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);



    cantor(n-1, x0, y0, x1, y1); //left
    cantor(n-1, x0, y0, x1, y1); //right



}

public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    double x0 = 0;
    double y0 = 0.9;
    double x1 = 0.9;
    double y1 = 0.9;

    StdDraw.line(x0, y0, x1, y1);

    cantor(n, x0, y0, x1, y1);

}
}
```

Comment: So far you've only stated facts. What's your question?

Comment: Please state the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are drawing the same line over and over. Something besides the depth (`n`) needs to change in the arguments to the recursive calls.  Putting a comment on the end of the line doesn't make it so.

Comment: You're right, that was my problem. It seems to be working now. Thank you!